# 3D ASCII Block Building

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

### Challenge

Write a program that takes an 11x11 array of integers, and constructs a 3D ASCII block building, where each value in the array represents the height of a column of blocks at the coordinates matching the array position. A negative height is a "floating" column - only the top block is visible.

### Example

```
                                                        __________________
                                        ___            /\__\__\__\__\__\__\
 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,      /\__\          /\/\__\__\__\__\__\__\
 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     /\/__/         /\/\/__/__/__/__/__/__/
 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,    /\/\__\        /\/\/\__\      /\/\/__/
 1, 0, 0, 7,-7,-7,-7,-7, 7, 0, 0,    \/\/\__\      /\/\/\/__/     /\/\/__/
 0, 0, 0, 7,-7,-7,-7,-7, 7, 0, 0,     \/\/__/     /\/\/\/\__\    /\/\/__/
 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,      \/\__\    /\/\/\/\/__/   /\/\/__/
 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,       \/__/    \/\/\/\/\__\_  \/\/__/
 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,                 \/\/\/\/__/_\_ \/__/
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,            ___   \/\/\/__/__/_\_         ___
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,           /\__\   \/\/__/__/__/_\       /\__\
 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,           \/\__\   \/__/__/__/__/       \/\__\
                                             \/\__\_________         ______\/\__\
                                              \/\__\__\__\__\       /\__\__\__\__\
                                               \/__/__/__/__/       \/__/__/__/__/
```

### Input

The input will be a list of 121 integers, either read from stdin (choice of separator is up to you), or passed in as an array (can be 1D or 2D).

Heights will be in the range -11 to 11.

### Output

The generated building can be written to stdout, displayed directly on the screen, or returned as a newline-separated string.

Leading and trailing whitespace is allowed.

### Building Rules

The shape of an individual 3D block looks like this:

```
 ___
/\__\
\/__/
```

And a 2x2x2 cube of blocks looks like this:

```
  ______
 /\__\__\
/\/\__\__\
\/\/__/__/
 \/__/__/
```

When blocks overlap, a higher block takes precedence over a lower one, blocks in front take precedence over those further back, and blocks to the left takes precedence over those to the right. The only special case is that the top line of a block should never overwrite any non-space character behind it.

The interpretation of column heights can best be explained by looking at a 2D representation from the side.

```
HEIGHT:  1    2    3   -3   -2   -1
                  __   __
             __  |__| |__|  __
        __  |__| |__|      |__|  __
       |__| |__| |__|           |__|
```

### Test Cases

If you want to try out your solution on a few more inputs, I've put together a couple of test cases [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8942545f3838de4a9130ff4966625d09).

### Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Ohh boy, get ready for 300+ byte solutions. Good challenge. +1

Comment: @totallyhuman Nah, Dennis is going to have a 9-byte solution for this in 20 minutes.

Comment: Does the perspective have to be as shown with the bottom left of the input data in the foreground? The fact that this is not the first or last element of data makes it harder. Is it acceptable to either 1. keep the mapping as is and draw output with the bottom right column in the foreground or 2. draw a mirror image or 90 deg rotation of the data? Either of these would make the last data element correspond with the column in the foreground, which would be easier.

Comment: I feel inclined to use a real game engine (or part of it) to render a photo and convert it to ASCII

Comment: @LevelRiverSt That seems like a reasonable request - you can choose the order of the 121 input elements to be whatever makes the most sense for your solution, as long as your ordering is consistent. It must be possible to produce every kind of layout that can be produced with the default order.

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/print-ascii-voxels)

Comment: This reminds me of [Snake Rattle 'n' Roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_Rattle_%27n%27_Roll)

Comment: @QBrute That's exactly the kind of thing I had in mind when I came up with this challenge. In my day, though, it was [Knight Lore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Lore) and [Alien 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_8) that popularised the isometric style.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>70</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```
≔Ｅ¹¹⮌Ｉ⪪Ｓ,θＦ²Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹«Ｊ⁻⁻⁺λκ×μ³ι⁻λκ≔§§θλμη¿∨⁼±η⊕κ‹κη¿ι“↗⊟&⁹κＵhnI”___
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU9LawIxED67v2LY0wQiGu3j0JOUHiy1leoxEBYd12A2rpusFEp/@zZrdbX0JTR888p885otk2K2TkxVDZzTqcVRkqMQHJ5pS4UjvE2cx0lutMehzUs/8YW2KTIOMY9ZeBw27CZarAvAHoOdFeI75zVq3ZdZPl3jSNvS7fXYBGU4rEKjqc7IYcahX7fVQT44u3QY0trvOPBDO6eXxm44mEDOgixrml4APhV4tykT4/CR0sQTLkN2aGcFZWQ9zXFVz3gg53BVlzEGdZlmMA4Heoyl7UiplJTSStlRqhMzIOPokFdKxWHYW1VBn0P3F0TQ@zdBHPxr3j5BCPeE7tmEqx9GNP7lXztc8PrksLM4IYjoU/gVZxIaHP8bVO2teQc) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ¹¹⮌Ｉ⪪Ｓ,θ
```

Read the array, split each line on commas and cast to integer, but also reverse each line, since we want to draw right-to-left so that left columns overwrite right columns. (Other dimensions already have desired overwriting behaviour.)

```
Ｆ²Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹«
```

Loop through i) top lines and bodies k) height l) rows m) columns. (Looping through first top lines and then bodies avoids overwriting bodies with top lines.)

```
Ｊ⁻⁻⁺λκ×μ³ι⁻λκ
```

Jump to the position of the cube.

```
≔§§θλμη
```

Fetch the height at the current row and column.

```
¿∨⁼±η⊕κ‹κη
```

Test whether a cube should be drawn at this height for this row and column.

```
¿ι“↗⊟&⁹κＵhnI”___
```

Draw the body or top of the cube.

Comment: When I change the first `3` to a `33`, I only get 11 blocks in the tower. In general towers seem to be capped at 11. How does that happen?

Comment: @Fabian I'm slightly confused that `Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹Ｆ¹¹` wasn't a clue...

Comment: I don't know this programming language, I just played around a bit with the TIO link.

Answer (score 34):

## C,  <s>376</s>   <s>350</s>   <s>313</s>   <s>309</s>  285 bytes

*Thanks to @Jonathan Frech for saving four bytes!*

```c
#define F for(
char*t,G[26][67],*s;i,j,e,k,v,x,y;b(){F s="\\/__//\\__\\ ___ ";*s;--y,s+=5)F e=5;e--;*t=*s<33&*t>32?*t:s[e])t=G[y]+x+e;}f(int*M){F;e<1716;++e)G[e/66][e%66]=32;F k=0;++k<12;)F i=0;i<11;++i)F j=11;j--;v+k||b())x=i+j*3+k,y=14+i-k,(v=M[i*11+j])>=k&&b();F;++e<26;)puts(G+e);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZfdbtowFMfveYqo0xBJbIHjxIEZd3dw1SdIoqhl6RaisanJEKjl2ZmT8hHwKbisY0WLjiC2f7KPz9@cg0f462i0XH74ktynk8QYGPc/HlqN0bfbB6tAw8BhUcD8CFk5T9EYJShDUzRDc37XMh8HRi6uwrAdx@12GMZxGBpxHBtXXNIYz1FuC88cGInweIIxtwph5X1Km1ZxTZ3PVvEpD5LILMQwmEf2zE744r6VTgrrRk7Nkz7xCeO2nZjDIGkz6UjyUX4K6vCBkYmOHMr6xOFyhVS20j4hsiuVzbGQr2O54tTOnp6kp@ZMpPbYonaG5oK4dooz1JqKmyC1CLHHkXktsmZTgnxQLth3GDd//iry1lCuzhdL6ZTx/TadtMzGY8OQT9mRTiRCgsgQVdfzQPlQZHQO2QZ03hwk6z4f4ZrJ5h7YeTXIjiy96fN0fXRRGSq5N1IDCQCCdiK4sdr42ipuwRvVd3kUS4HNVXsjuQNI3tEV6C@CLsJrK0P7Iohrg/i8oLaPZ4sjJLmjSE51JSfVeabl5jQ98HRBpgv6W9A9BOItiHVB7Rn1fXyjXR@L41YZSHKqSO4CkrtVcmM7SbPMmKzqr0l@uAJQ3cTunJDi3kMm@regkl3gX7mrSO4Bkj8L7EHm7xzjWu1UD3sd9HSP8f8JasexpgxeW00ZSHJPkZypkhOCDtsZwL2dXzZ4tjhCkjNFcv9ILQfSx7tIca5Sz3a9Bmu58m8Xu6@f8cISu69I3gUkl/mCreo37q5sVdfZXubSBC@qThIEXoZAEHo/Ewj4CEneVSTv1SQ/KUzgVfEFkK5NA/TgCzII@kgth@Bm5FnsaYLbuklXezsQHk8X3ETgGLgb1j@5pfWk5ovlbw)

**Unrolled:**

```c
#define F for(

char *t, G[26][67], *s;
i, j, e, k, v, x, y;

b()
{
    F s="\\/__//\\__\\ ___ "; *s; --y, s+=5)
        F e=5; e--; *t=*s<33&*t>32?*t:s[e])
            t = G[y]+x+e;
}

f(int*M)
{
    F; e<1716; ++e)
        G[e/66][e%66] = 32;

    F k=0; ++k<12;)
        F i=0; i<11; ++i)
            F j=11; j--; v+k||b())
                x = i+j*3+k,
                y = 14+i-k,
                (v=M[i*11+j])>=k && b();

    F; ++e<26;)
        puts(G+e);
}
```

Comment: Can `26*66` not be `1716`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Sure, I forgot about that.

Comment: `*s==32` -> `*s<33`.

Comment: `for(e=k=1;e;++k)for(e=` -> `for(k=1;e;++k)for(e=`.

Comment: `#define B b(...)&++e` -> `#define B++e&b(...)` (assuming `b` does not depend on `e`, which I think it does not).

Comment: @JonathanFrech It doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: `#define F for(` and using whitespace saves no less bytes than `#define F for` and using an open-parenthesis after the `F`, and it somewhat adds to readability... other than that (very minor OCD detail) this is a great answer! +1

Comment: @MDXF Thanks, but doesn't `#define F for(` save one byte over `#define F for`, because there are two instances where with `#define F for(` there is no need for whitespace after `F`, because the init part of the loop is empty and the `F` can be directly followed by the semicolon?

Comment: @MDXF There are two occurrences of `F;` in this code. Redefining `F` to be `for` instead of `for(` saves one byte, replacing both `F;`s with `F(;` adds two. In total this would add one byte.

Comment: @both Oh, I didn't notice that, sorry!

Comment: [262 bytes](https://tio.run/##vZLfaoMwFMbv@xQyGJh/1Kit0Jj10qs@gUpoJd2irBvVXUjrXt0ldhUZbuvG1vCBnO/8knOSY0bus6xts4f1HlY4imnguymGJVM4xwWWuGYbW4LD9mlvl/wmSaZCTKdJIkSSWEII64ZpmJAal4jPgMEknzFJiPbvPPcIq9DzlrDiZSzThQMqHqEazgOkUA49VCDJmq2tdhVcnapIbnroTgCR3sNf5e08WHrugjrMAAV3GEJFSF3W1VM6ViGl2lSdkXMd5Hq/RMXxuLEBqDn1kSIF1qevYgUpRXkKwlOWPb9UpR0B1rS6DetxrXY2mBwmll7GUDsN0Di1eGedEmZ52HK@Ug@6fw7SsxdgMpAOP4DOj8H5N6V7b3Zpjz42T6XvRgcgHQFH9Uuw1yB/Vsc1bNJ9zc9nBgze437k7sjInUsH9I@gj8lZ5mk/BckgSa4LXtzj1d5xbOSuHnnTvgE), I couldn't fit all test cases on the link due to the character limit, just copy them from the answer

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>277</s> 251 bytes

```
a=>(n=55,$=f=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>f(i)),S=$(_=>$(_=>' ')),n=11,$(l=>$(z=>$(y=>$(x=>(x=10-x,X=x*3+y+z,Y=y-z+n,Z=a[y][x])<=z&&Z+z+1?0:l?['/\\__\\','\\/__/'].map(s=>S[++Y].splice(X,5,...s)):S[Y].splice(X+1,3,...'___'))))),S.map(r=>r.join``).join`
`)
```

```js
f=

a=>(n=55,$=f=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>f(i)),S=$(_=>$(_=>' ')),n=11,$(l=>$(z=>$(y=>$(x=>(x=10-x,X=x*3+y+z,Y=y-z+n,Z=a[y][x])<=z&&Z+z+1?0:l?['/\\__\\','\\/__/'].map(s=>S[++Y].splice(X,5,...s)):S[Y].splice(X+1,3,...'___'))))),S.map(r=>r.join``).join`
`)

console.log(f([
 [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -11],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 7,-7,-7,-7,-7, 7, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 7,-7,-7,-7,-7, 7, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 11]
]))
```

Saved 26 bytes from [@Neil's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153109/3d-ascii-block-building/153135#comment374122_153135).

#### Ungolfed

```
a=>(
    n=55,
    $=f=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>f(i)),
    S=$(_=>$(_=>' ')),
    n=11,
    $(l=>
        $(z=>$(y=>$(x=>(
            x=10-x,
            X=x*3+y+z,
            Y=y-z+n,
            Z=a[y][x],
            Z<=z && Z+z+1 || (
                l
                ? ['/\\__\\','\\/__/'].map(s=>S[++Y].splice(X,5,...s))
                : S[Y].splice(X+1,3,...'___')
            )
        ))))
    ),
    S.map(r=>r.join``).join`\n`
)
```

Comment: `,$(w=>$(z=>$(y=>$(x=>(Z=a[y][x=10-x,X=x*3+y+z,Y=y-z+n,x])<=z&&Z+z+1?0:w?['/\\__\\','\\/__/'].map(s=>S[++Y].splice(X,5,...s)):S[Y].splice(X+1,3,...'___'))))),` seems to save 26 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Brilliant! Drawing all the top lines first saves me the trouble of checking for non-spaces.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 243 bytes

```python
a=input()
s=eval(`[[' ']*55]*23`)
for h in range(7986):
 k=h%3;x=h/3%11;y=h/33%11;z=h/363%11;i=h/3993;u=y+z-x*3+30;v=y-z+10
 if~-(z>=a[y][10-x]!=~z):
	if i*k:s[v+k][u:u+5]='\//\____/\\'[k%2::2]
	if~-i:s[v][u+1+k]='_'
for l in s:print''.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDLboMwFETX5SvcBTLPgnEhBeT@iLESFqG4IEC8BCz4dWpHKq0ipUmtWczIR77j28x9XlfetqWEV83Qa7rSkfOYltqJUgggM3yfGR4@6UpWtyAHvAJtWn2ctUP4FuiRAgqSqzieSO5gFaF4lubiFumCi@XShiGOBzKbiz0Z2MRuPJLZXkzkKoBnq60t7ySlM6PItSf2TNZFvP7EM8CNIuroaBaMDtFg@ozAxHGSozhOkkBaqF4UeUyyq80lKkATCZ7AI7zULmXtLmpaXvUQvnzWvNJKfdsoxRZwbwsxC1DvT8R9EEHf6WDZvyTijrj/QIKbg/bk3@/yagGxANEeXX8a3d/LY8iun5tdjH0B)

A Python translation of Neil’s Charcoal approach.

Comment: Nice to see a golfed Python solution for this. My Python proof-of-concept was more than 900 bytes!

Comment: `+1+k` -> `-~k`.

Answer (score 5):

## Tcl, 380 <s>409</s> bytes

User **[sergiol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29325/sergiol)** has been busy crunching this down very nicely:

```
set X [read stdin]
proc L {a b c d e s} {time {incr z
set y -1
time {incr y
set x -1
time {if {abs([set Z [lindex $::X [expr ($y+1)*11-[incr x]-1]]])==$z|$z<$Z} {set s [string repl [string repl $s [set i [expr -3*$x+57*$y-55*abs($z)+701]] $i+$b $a] [incr i $c] $i+$e $d]}} 11} 11} 12
set s}
puts [L /\\__\\ 4 56 \\/__/ 4 [L "" -1 -55 ___ 2 [string repe [string repe \  55]\n 23]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHbaoNQEHw/XzGU85AoEo/xQkPzB/mAEhVJ9LQIqRW1oKZ@u10vpVpMSh8W3ZnZmV0twkvb5rLAM9xMniLkRRQnPkuz9xAHXE84I0QEibzBtYjfJK5xEmaoWTdVQRNsglY9Wk7QF/I45yu3w49wL3ESyRJ8t6NAWaYZVrxSxVoRQnN7i9LXhO/76/2e15@8fuJHCu6mc7h5kcXJKzKZXuYN70jSxKOptlV4qVqOwivNspRuA16vVUcna/BY5Wfwk48hMQYPB1SCR37TQIixjP6evGHpR0ERB2w8Lwg8DyYsG563CYINvRPx8EBHg8IQBAGM6Xpy3niAZfleAmNLd7YtoOOnBOb9rBgojMYXuOlcx5tseNpUzrKf5oy8NWq7/pHO0KnEpPQeH/j/as0x4y@tMbntxr4Y99Vs0hoY9N@csaA3Oi3YnQ/664PYN7QL5prF7v@wKW6yLw)

#### Original Content

```
set xs [read stdin]
proc L {a b c d e s} {set z 0
while {[incr z]<12} {set y -1
while {[incr y]<11} {set x -1
while {[incr x]<11} {set Z [lindex $::xs [expr ($y+1)*11-$x-1]]
if {abs($Z)==$z||$z<$Z} {set i [expr -3*$x+57*$y-55*abs($z)+701]
set s [string repl [string repl $s $i $i+$b $a] [incr i $c] $i+$e $d]}}}}
set s}
puts [L /\\__\\ 4 56 \\/__/ 4 [L "" -1 -55 ___ 2 [string repe [string repe \  55]\n 23]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHRboJAEHy/r5iYe1DJRQ5FU6N/4BcoF6JwbS8x1ABNEfXb7SLXFFq0KWEDuzM7O3uXR/vrNdM5igybVG9jZHlsEsUO6VuEFU5b7BAhhkZ2walilnDZx6vZa5w2JolSlGohPQseIWQbPRIqLVr8QosGusZmb5JYF@DzeeVHF4cUfX505GAopeCFkEox80yudlmfrwfLJS/PZ14u@NpqGNslxkNeOP5syI/C94c3fjlwZq5UrOKRepanJnlBqg/7dsIzcEOvw3fgW4XaKVUidatq8Fhd6KmVLuzwnpPeCqMgCMMgwAT@FEEwCsMR/RPQ69HiICMIwxBec5xuJwHg@ypI4I2VUtcr4OI7JNp5KxhoGLV3YM2@Cp@w@julmHXriZnFfcut8idaw6WQjXBv9Rr/L3diZ/zF9Rq73fEL61dMieuh5n9hXgffq7hgDw70x4FM73A7xIXPHl9Ysz5hnw)

Alas, it is what it is. It’s only a tad easier on the eyes when “ungolfed”

```
set s [string repeat [string repeat " " 55]\n 23]

proc loops {s0 i0 io s1 i1} {
  set z  0; while {[incr z] < 12} {
  set y -1; while {[incr y] < 11} {
  set x -1; while {[incr x] < 11} {
    set Z [lindex $::xs [expr {($y+1) * 11 - $x - 1}]]
    if {abs($Z) == $z || $z < $Z} {
        set i [expr {-3*$x + 57*$y - 55*abs($z) + 701}]
        set ::s [string replace $::s $i $i+$i0 $s0]
        incr i $io
        set ::s [string replace $::s $i $i+$i1 $s1]
    }
  } } }
}

loops ""      -1 -55 \
       ___     2
loops /\\__\\  4  56 \
      \\/__/   4

puts $s
```

Builds a string, as per requirements. Takes the array from stdin. Goes from bottom to top, front to back, right to left over the string data. Does it in two passes, once for the top edge and again for the rest of the body of each cube.

I tried to make it smaller using some sweet functional lambda mojo, but alas, that made it larger.

Comment: You can golf: https://tio.run/##lZHdboJAEIXv9ylOzF4oZqOLrqRG38AnUDZEYdtuQqgBmuLfs9NBaAqt2pRkAjPfmTOzSx7GZZmZHEWGTWq2EbI8solm@/QtxAqnLXYIEcEgu@D08Wpjg9PGJmGKo15Il4pV@wFCsg49EJUNLX7RokXX2MQ2iUwBPp9Xe5hin6LPD0M5cKQUvBBSa2afaZtd1ufrwXLJj@czPy74uvGgrixPbfKC1OzjbsIrSBrbOIuJw4uh8hx@EEo5V8/jYOiNaQq4HfId@FajXtSCh3XVgEf6Qg@7Dryw/XtOziuMfD8IfB9TqBl8fxQEI/om0OvRuUEzEAQB3PZWppv4gFLaT@BOtNZlCYzxHRLdvBMMNIzab7B2X8WnrH7PKLzbfsJruGq0Vf5ExxhTyFaMr/Wa/1c7bWb8pXVbZ7uzL5p9xYy0Lmr9F3Nv6N1KC/bgQn9cyOyO9oa5UOzxD2vXp@wT

Comment: More golfing: https://tio.run/##lVFbboMwEPz3KUaVPxIQCiY81Ki5QU6QYKEE3MpSShFQCUg4OzWPqBCRVP1YzM7M7uzaeXhumkzkKDIcUnGMkOWRjDlJ0q8QO1yOOCFEBIGsxiWXnwIXGYcpKtKWlTAYGaFlhxZ3aNGhexzOMo5EAbrZtH6iSFIsaKmzpcaYQQuDcU7ku3I9ZQu6X263tLpeafVG98q87aGqsjyV8QdSkZynCW1JpZFDZ2Ot0UJ3PI2WhuNoXc9qqXumcgGVOj2BHjkO3YgSNOxRARrxugZjuH2sbv6sJsl3rkx2WPl@EPg@bDgufH8VBCv1r4iXF7U6lB2CIIA1HlBMEx9wHO7HsNac86YBTPwGwzSfBIEyU@Uz3Liu5W3Sn64Kb76f4Q28M2jb/FWtYapgozA7vOf/q7UHj7@01mi3B/NimNdwldZCr79x1ozearUgTy707kLcB9qZ5oZDnj/YGLfJDw

Comment: More: https://tio.run/##lVFbboMwEPz3KUaRP5IgFEx4qFFzg5wgsYUScCtLKUVAJSDl7NQ8qkJFUvVjZHZmdmdt8vDaNJnMUWQ4pfIcIcsjFQuSpO8hDridcUGICBJZjVuu3iRuKg5TVKRtK2EyMmLLji1@sUXHHnG6qjiSBehu1@bJIkmxpKXBVmvGTFqYTAiiXnTqJVvS42q/p9UnrZ7pUWe3I3RTlqcqfkUqk@u0oK2oPWoYbG7XtDBcf01L03XX3chqZfiWDgFVBr2AngVO3YYKNOxZCRqJugZjA@xu@awmyUeuIw7YcB4EnMOB64HzTRBs9LcWFgt9b@gwBEEAe7yenBYccF3BY9hbIUTTABZ@wDCtJyDQYbp9Rhv3tbpD@tPT8Ofnmf6gu4O3rZ/0NSwNNoLV8b3@X68zZPzltUd3u7Mvhn1NT3tt9P5vzZ7x260X5MGD/noQ7453Zrjpksc/bMw75As

Comment: Yet more: https://tio.run/##lVFbboMwEPz3KUaRPxIQCiYB1Ki5QU6Q2EIJuJWllCKgEpBydmoeVaEiqfoxMjszu@M1eXhtmkzmKDKcUnmOkOWRigVJ0vcQB9zOuCBEBImsxi1XbxI3FYcpKtK2lbAYGbFlxxY/bFsecbqqOJIF6G7XBskiSbGkpclWBmPWqWsthMWEIOpFh16yJT2u9ntafdLqmR7rfpBuzfJUxa9IZXKdFrQVtUcN462NQQvT9Q1aWq5rdCOrlenbOgRUmfQCehbosxVo2LMSNBJ1DcYGON1GWU2Sj1xHHLDmPAg4xxauB87XQbDW31pYLPTa0GEIggDO@HpyWnDAdQWP4WyEEHbTADZ@wDCtJyDQabp/Rhv3tfqW9Ken4c/Ps/xBdwdvWz/pPWwNNoLd8b3@X@92yPjL64x2u3NfDPe1PO110Pu/NWfG77RekAcP@utBvDvemeGWSx7/sDG/JV8

Comment: More yet: https://tio.run/##lVHtboJAEPx/TzEx90MlRA75SE19A59AIETh2lxiKQGaoJZnp3tAU2zQpj82sDOzM7tQJae2LWWFukRQyEOKskpVFrG8eE@ww/WAIxKkkCgbXCv1JnFVWVLgwvTYGaZgI/TcofUIfSGPYzkPNL5HcFJZKmvwzUYnyjovMOdnQyyWQphB51FHpoiiaLHd8ssnvzzzPSXrcRooq0JlryhkfrptuCZJowZTc73kteH6S342XXepV@CXheFbZA2uDH4EP0ToExV40qMSPI2aBkIMZXcHlQ3LPyqK2GEVhnEchnDgegjDVRyv6J2I2YyuBoUhjmPY4/XkbRMCrhuFGew13Wm1LWDhpwRu@5tioDSan@DGc5p3WP/0qPxpP9MfeHfQ6v6J7rCoxKisDu/5/2qdIeMvrT267c6@GPY1PdLa6PXfnD2ht7UW7MEH/fVBvDvaCXPTZY9/2Bh32Bc

Comment: Even more: https://tio.run/##lVHbaoNQEHw/XzGU85AoEo/xQkPzB/mAEhVJ9LQIqRW1oKZ@u10vpVpMSh8W3ZnZmV0twkvb5rLAM9xMniLkRRQnPkuz9xAHXE84I0QEibzBtYjfJK5xEmaoWTdVQRNsglY9Wk7QF/I45yu3w49wL3ESyRJ8t6NAWaYZVrxSxVoRQnN7i9LXhO/76/2e15@8fuJHCu6mc7h5kcXJKzKZXuYN70jSxKOptlV4qVqOwivNspRuA16vVUcna/BY5Wfwk48hMQYPB1SCR37TQIixjP6evGHpR0ERB2w8Lwg8DyYsG563CYINvRPx8EBHg8IQBAGM6Xpy3niAZfleAmNLd@ptC@j4KYF5PysGSqP5BW461/EmG542lbPspzkjb43arn@kO3QqMSm9xwf@v1pzzPhLa0xuu7Evxn01m7QGBv03ZyzojU4LdueD/vog9g3tgrlmsfs/bIqb7As

Comment: The last 0 is not part of the answer! My fault!

Comment: Oops! I'll fix it ASAP.

Comment: I fixed it myself

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>117</s> <s>116</s> 112 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
a←23 55⍴0⋄{i←11 0+⍵+.×3 2⍴3-7897⊤⍨6⍴5⋄(,2 5↑i↓a)←745366⊤⍨10⍴4⋄(3⍴i↓1⌽¯1⊖a)⌈←1}¨j[⍋-/↑j←⍸↑⎕↑¨⊂⌽1,11/⍳2]⋄' _/\'[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZLPTsJAEMbvfYq5oaHITsu28ixITBuDgZDg1RgvxCAp1GiM@gIeuPWgJl681DeZFylfaUAoTaPEA8nsZjr7@3b@bL2Lfu3s0usPzhO5e@oOZHSvDBnfdhIPrmWT1hK@K5ncXHURYCZVlfCjevT9YpOFI7vmHjddCV4lnDn41kAPTIu0jB6gePQOIXMb2nacDGIFqpFSNpwUYZl@xRFL8Ax4Ok7TXMezXkvCSa2Oa3qISPgJDyVij2cSDKFhk7ku4ZvVxm0VOq2fVFpeO0H1iU@pJhjaRKrEDN/MOOufOV6GXIqjzYXQJqt2YZ3y/KuQ/mWdDSLMCu3xGsfbXKHtxK3s53hlRsfAO/uGsXxHamIerNKNM48QWqiWK99aHGFGuW2dL9Lkz/eJzxrn9RHEUbNcszUD9291LRLs06DQesF/Mgc)